# Why i'm getting PingException?

Tags: c#, exception, ping, pingexception

It was all working an hour ago and many days ago.
The link i try to ping is:

[Link to ping](http://www.sat24.com/image.ashx?country=afis&type=slide&time=&ir=true&index=1&sat=)

This is the code in form1:

```
nc = new NetworkConnection();
bool bval = nc.PingConnection(satellite_address);

if (bval)
{
    label19.Visible = true;
    label19.Text = "Internet Access";
}
else
{
    label19.Visible = true;
    label19.Text = "No Internet Access";
}
```

When it's trying to execute this line:

```
bool bval = nc.PingConnection(satellite_address);
```

It's going to the `nc` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace mws
{
    class NetworkConnection
    {
        public NetworkConnection()
        {    
        }

        public bool PingConnection(string url)
        {
            bool Result = false;

            using (Ping pp = new Ping())
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("samplestring");
                int timeout = 120;

                try
                {
                    PingReply reply = pp.Send(url, timeout, buffer);
                    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        Result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Result = false;
                }
            }
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the nc class when trying to do the line:

```
PingReply reply = pp.Send(url, timeout, buffer);
```

It's jumping to the catch block and throws a PingException:

> An exception occurred during a Ping request

And then in Form1 the result it return is that there is no internet access but there is internet and I can surf to the url no problems.

This is the complete exception message:

```
  System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An exception occurred during a Ping request.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
       at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer)
       at mws.NetworkConnection.PingConnection(String url) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\NetworkConnection.cs:line 33
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=No such host is known
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=11001
       NativeErrorCode=11001
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
            at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
            at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
            at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
       InnerException:
```

Line 33 is:

```
PingReply reply = pp.Send(url, timeout, buffer);
```

What could be the reason that this exception show up ? it didn't show up before ever my program is working for some yeras now.

And what or how should i handle it ?

Comment: Are you behind a Proxy?

Comment: Yaha no. I'm not behind.

Comment: line 33 is not problem problem is in ping request.

Comment: Try `ping "http://www.sat24.com/image.ashx?country=afis&type=slide&time=&ir=true&index=1&sat="` on the command line. Does it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot pass a full URL to the [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms144954%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method of the Ping class. The parameter `string hostNameOrAddress` needs to be

> A String that identifies the computer that is the destination for the ICMP echo message. The value specified for this parameter can be a **host name** or a **string representation of an IP address**.

So you can only pass in `www.sat24.com` or the IP of the host `82.94.176.100` (taken from the CommandLine `ping www.sat24.com`).

If you want to pass a full URL to your method you need to extract the Host from that URL to perform your Ping. For this case you can take the Uri class

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
PingReply reply = pp.Send(uri.Host, timeout, buffer);
```

Comment: thank you. typo in my ip address. a comma instead of a period. hard to spot!

Answer (score 1):

```
PingReply reply = pp.Send(url, timeout, buffer);
```

"No such host is known"

My bet is that no such host is known.

You should ping "www.sat24.com" not "http://www.sat24.com/..."

Ping.Send doesn't say it accepts a URL

```
public PingReply Send(
    string hostNameOrAddress,
    int timeout,
    byte[] buffer
)

hostNameOrAddress   A String that identifies the computer that is the destination for the ICMP echo message. The value specified for this parameter can be a host name or a string representation of an IP address.
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144954(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144954%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)