# Meaning of PingException "No such host is known"

Tags: c#, .net, ping

I wrote a Windows Service which monitors devices on our LAN by (among other things) pinging them (using `Ping.Send()`; .NET 4.6.1). For a small number of PCs (3), I "occasionally" (once/day?) will get a `PingException` from `Send(<ipaddr>, 5000)`, with `InnerException.Message == "No such host is known"`. The next time the `Send()` is executed (~60 seconds later), it succeeds. I am using an IP address, as opposed to a name, so it's not a DNS issue.

I talked to the network admins about this issue, but they don't believe anything is wrong with the physical hardware. What other problems could this error be indicating?

Comment: It would be greate to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sending strictly to IP addresses or are you using names? It sounds like a DNS error.

Comment: Pinging too often?? - devices/servers can limit the rate of Pings accepted.

Comment: @AlexK. yes, using IP addresses - I thought it might be a DNS problem too, but switched to IP addrs, and still seeing the problem.

Comment: Sounds like DNS lookup failure. Could be it thinks the IP is s host name, e.g. it had an extra space or stray character

Comment: Possible duplicate ? [Why i'm getting PingException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560913/why-im-getting-pingexception)

Comment: @Kaj not a duplicate - that question was using a URL as opposed to a name/IP addr.

Comment: @PaulF the `Ping` is occurring every 60-90 seconds - that shouldn't be a problem should it?

Comment: To the downvoter: If you'd like to share what is unclear, I'd be happy to fix.

Comment: Have you got a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: At that rate I wouldn't expect there to be any problem at all - typically I've seen setups of 1-5 pings per/second limit - not per minute.

Comment: [This question](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/packet-lost-whenever-1st-ping-on-newly-configure-interface/td-p/2639213) suggests losing Ping ICMP packets is typical behaviour for Cisco routers under certain conditions - maybe the same applies to the routers you are using. Have you tried pinging again immediately after failure?

Comment: @PaulF yes, doing another ping "immediately" (I get an email saying the ping failed then I immediately manually test), results in success. We do have Cisco routers, but the article seems to say this only happens the first time one tries to ping, but we are seeing after pinging numerous times.

Comment: @Conrad: The second answer does mention the ARP cache having a timeout period after which it is flushed & the next packet lost - which could account for your intermittent failures.

Comment: Also check the full exception details - including stack traces of the exception AND any inner exceptions - they may give more information to help. It is also worthwhile considering that a Ping is not guaranteed to succeed even if the server/device is active & accessible - various things can happen to delay the reply beyond the timeout - so you should consider having automatic retries before error reporting - if everything is on a LAN then 5 seconds timeout may be excessive (this can be checked) & reduced to 1 second & only report an error after 5 retries (for example).

Comment: @PaulF working on getting a stack trace.

Comment: If possible, arrange the try/catch statement such that the IP address passed to the send method is accessible & can be logged as well to check if it is in someway invalid as per Kitson88's suggestion. Basically get as much information as possible - it may very well be that the IP address is valid as you expect - but there is no harm in proving what you are 100% certain is correct is actually correct - all of us make the mistake of skipping that step at some point only to realise we could have saved hours of effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Ping.Send()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) has various parameters which includes a parameter type of `string` than can either be a valid IP address or valid host-name. I suspect that your using one of the `string` parameters and sometimes passing an invalid IP (extra space, invalid IP etc...) and the `Send()` method conditionally resolves that you must be passing a host-name hence the exception regarding DNS.

Rather than send a `string`, why not utilize the parameter of type [`IPAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx) as you've already stated that it should always be an IP. You can do this by attempting to parse the `string` into an `IPAddress` as shown below:

```
if (IPAddress.TryParse("**IP String**", out var ip))
{
      using (var pong = new Ping())
      {
         pong.Send(ip);
         //Etc...
      }  
}
```

Note that you will still need to fix your invalid data whichever way you look at it.

Comment: Thanks, but the IP address is hard-coded into the software, so I know it's not changing at all between calls to `Ping.Send()`. Also as mentioned, I am using IP addresses, so DNS is not involved here.

Comment: @Conrad Is the value passed as type `string` or `IPAddress`? Trust me that the your hostname exception is only thrown when it looks up an hostname via DNS so it's either corrupt data or an unknown hostname. As well as previous answers, I've noticed comments are also telling you this. Try out the above and see what happens (maybe remove tryparse and catch the exception). What do you have to lose.

Comment: I did double-check again, and there was indeed some corruption! Took multiple eyes here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Conrad No worries and glad you got it sorted.